# how to have bg-url (tailwindcss) working with rails_blob_url / url_for (active_storage)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have a rails 7 app running with tailwindcss-rails and I am trying to display a background image (cover) using `bg-[url(...)]`

But it doesnt work with rails 7 active_storage
Seems like the rails_blob_url is not being recognized by tailwindcss-rails...

I have an html.erb displaying :

```
<div class="h-24 w-fullbg-[url(https://placekitten.com/1400)]bg-no-repeat"></div>
<div class="w-full h-24 bg-no-repeat bg-[url(<%= rails_blob_url(current_house.hero_image) -%>)]"></div>
<%= image_tag rails_blob_url(current_house.hero_image) -%>
```

First div shows the image correctly

Second div doesnt display anything (blank):

```
<div class="w-full h-24 bg-no-repeat bg-[url(http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBIUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--1f68a32dc902558a4ee5a14ca06057885f50ca7d/01-liveroom.jpg)]"> </div>
```

image_tag displayed correctly so the issue doesnt come from generated url

Comment: after digging around :
Since <%= %> are generated on .html.erb evaluation, tailwindcss watch can never compile the proper css tags.
So it make sense that it does not work.

PS : I end up using `current_house.hero_image.url` instead of `rails_blob_url(...)`
with this in application controller   (to avoid SetCurrent error)
```
before_action do
    ActiveStorage::Current.url_options = { protocol: request.protocol, host: request.host, port: request.port }
  end
```